# dynamic binding elements not working on keypress

Tags: jquery, html

here is my js code

```
var dd = $('#ulscroller > li:last-child').attr('id');
    var to_int_dd = parseInt(dd)+1;
    var input_id = $('#'+dd+' > input:first-child').attr('id');
    var to_int_input_id = parseInt(input_id)+1;
    var del_id = parseInt(input_id)-40000;
    var to_int_del_id = parseInt(del_id)+1;
    var html_input = '';
    $('#'+input_id).keypress('keypress', function(event) {
        var keyCode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keyCode == 13) {
            html_input = '<li id="'+to_int_dd+'"><input type="text" class="search-list-input" id="'+to_int_input_id+'" name="'+to_int_input_id+'" style="width:180px;"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="'+to_int_del_id+'" onClick="clearInput(this)">×</span></li>';
            $('#ulscroller').append(html_input);
            $('#'+to_int_input_id).focus();
            $('#'+input_id).on('keypress', '#'+to_int_input_id, function(){

            });
            dd = parseInt(dd)+1;
            to_int_dd = parseInt(dd)+1;
            input_id = parseInt(input_id)+1;
            to_int_input_id = parseInt(input_id)+1;
            del_id = parseInt(del_id)+1;
            to_int_del_id = parseInt(del_id)+1;
            html_input = '';
        }
    });
```

and here is my html

```
<form method="get" action="<?= base_url('search/search_by_list')?>" id="onEnterId">
                                      <div style="background-color:#e18942; border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px; color:#fff; height:30px; margin-top:-10px;">
                                        <label id="clearList" style="padding:7px 0px 0px 10px; cursor:pointer; width:50px; font-weight:normal;" onclick="clearAll()">Clear</label>
                                        <label id="help" style="padding:7px 0px 0px 10px; cursor:pointer; width:50px; font-weight:normal; float:right;">Help</label>
                                      </div>
                                      <div style="height:250px; overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden; width:100%;">
                                          <ul style="list-style:decimal;" id="ulscroller">
                                             <li id="10001"><input type="text" class="search-list-input" id="90001" name="90001"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="50001" onClick="clearInput(this);">×</span></li>
                                             <li id="10002"><input type="text" class="search-list-input" id="90002" name="90002"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="50002" onClick="clearInput(this);">×</span></li>
                                             <li id="10003"><input type="text" class="search-list-input" id="90003" name="90003"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="50003" onClick="clearInput(this);">×</span></li>
                                             <li id="10004"><input type="text" class="search-list-input" id="90004" name="90004"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="50004" onClick="clearInput(this);">×</span></li>
                                             <li id="10005"><input type="text" class="search-list-input" id="90005" name="90005"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="50005" onClick="clearInput(this);">×</span></li>
                                             <li id="10006"><input type="text" class="search-list-input" id="90006" name="90006"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="50006" onClick="clearInput(this);">×</span></li>
                                             <li id="10007"><input type="text" class="search-list-input" id="90007" name="90007"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="50007" onClick="clearInput(this);">×</span></li>
                                             <li id="10008"><input type="text" class="search-list-input" id="90008" name="90008"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="50008" onClick="clearInput(this);">×</span></li>
                                             <li id="10009"><input type="text" class="search-list-input" id="90009" name="90009"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="50009" onClick="clearInput(this);">×</span></li>
                                             <li id="10010"><input type="text" class="search-list-input" id="90010" name="90010"><span style="cursor:pointer;" id="50010" onClick="clearInput(this);">×</span></li>
                                          </ul>
                                      </div>
                                      <div style="background-color:#e18942; border-radius:0px 0px 5px px; text-align:center; height:50px; margin-top:10px;">
                                            <input type="button" id="onEnterSearch" name="Search" value="Search By List" style="background:transparent; color:#fff; margin-top:20px;">  
                                      </div>
```

I want to add input field on enter on previous specified html which is the last one. On enter works fine on last one and focus goes to next dynamic one. But next on enter on dynamic one is not working. For next dynamic one creating I have to go to the last static one. Please help me because I am wondering for some days.

Comment: Tags should be Javascript, jQuery and HTML, there is almost no php in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
    <button>Add</button>
</div>

cnt=0;

$('button').click(function(){
$('div').prepend('<p class="usual" data-id="'+cnt+'">alert me</p><input type="text" data-id="'+cnt+'">');
    cnt++;
})
$( document ).on( "click", ".usual", function() {
    alert($(this).data("id"));
})
$( document ).on( "keypress", "input", function() {
    alert($(this).data("id"));
})
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfLeu6uj/2/).

Comment: `.live` is deprecated!

Comment: same problem occurs when i am using .on . Means the focus goes to dynamic input. But for new dynamic content on onenter I have to go to the last static input field.

Answer (score 0):

You are using event binding wrong. Use `.on` to bind event:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#'+input_id, function(event) {/* ... */ });
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. But .on is not working. And what should be the document.

Comment: Same problem occurs when am using $(document).on('keypress', '#'+input_id, function(event) {/* ... */ });

Comment: @user3296979 have you tried `click` instead of `keypress`?

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery.on function,

```
$(document).on('keypress','selector',function(e){
   // To do here
});
```

refer jQuery document http://api.jquery.com/on/